# riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb not found after installing gcc-riscv64-linux-gnu Debian

Tags: debian, gnu

I am trying to debug xv6 using gdb. My system is Debian 11. I had already run the following command:

`sudo apt-get install git build-essential gdb-multiarch qemu-system-misc gcc-riscv64-linux-gnu binutils-riscv64-linux-gnu`

To install all the necessary packages. Running it again yeilds `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.` However, running `riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb` yields `-bash: riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb: command not found`. My understanding is that installing `gcc-riscv64-linux-gnu` should install `riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb` without any further action necessary. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you’re interested in `riscv64-unknown-elf` (as opposed to `riscv64-linux-gnu`), you should install `gcc-riscv64-unknown-elf` (which will pull in the relevant `binutils`).

However none of these packages install target-specific variants `gdb`. With `gdb-multiarch`, you need [to specify the target architecture](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Targets.html) yourself:

```
$ gdb-multiarch
(gdb) set architecture riscv:rv64
The target architecture is set to "riscv:rv64".
```